# Handling request body with different types

Tags: json, go, reflection

Let's say a back end application has such a request. As you can see this is an array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "section_id": "8ad1f7cc-a510-48ee-b4fa-bedbee444a84", // (uuid - string)
        "section_name": "First section"
    },
    {
        "section_id": 1556895, // (int)
        "section_name": "Second section"
    }
]
```

I want to parse this array. Depending on the section id type, the application needs to do different things. How to bypass strict typing?

```
requestBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)

if err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(requestBody), &sections); err != nil {
    println(err)
}

for _, section := range sections {
    if reflect.TypeOf(section.ID) == string {
        // block 1
    } reflect.TypeOf(section.ID) == int {
        // block 2
    }
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/rBWy9pufl2-

Comment: Duplicate. This comes ups soooo often....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```golang
type section struct {
    ID interface{} `json:"section_id"`
    Name string `json:"section_name"`
}

dec := json.NewDecoder(requestBody)
dec.UseNumber()
var sections []section
if err := dec.Decode([]byte(request.Body), &sections); err != nil {
    println(err)
}

for _, section := range sections {
    if reflect.TypeOf(section.ID).String() == "string" {
        // block 1
    } reflect.TypeOf(section.ID).String() == "json.Number" {
        n := section.ID.Int64()
        // block 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only mistake here is the part where you check the type of the id. I changed it to `if reflect.TypeOf(section.ID).String() == "string"` etc. Also I notice that `1556895` value return `float64` type. I thought it must be `int`. So strange.

Comment: About `float64`, this is what happens by default for numbers when type is given as `interface{}`. There is a `UseNumber()` option on the JSON decoder to keep numbers as a json.Number, you can convert it later.

Comment: I have such error `Cannot use requestBody (type []byte) as type io.Reador` in this part of the code: `json.NewDecoder(requestBody)`.

Comment: Don't use `requestBody`, just `request.Body`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you can do this:

```
type Section struct {
   ID interface{} `json:"section_id"`
   SectionName string `json:"section_name"
}

for _, section := range sections {
   if str,ok:=section.ID.(string); ok {
   } else if number, ok:=section.ID.(float64); ok {
   }
}
```

Or:

```
type Section struct {
   ID json.RawMessage `json:"section_id"`
   SectionName string `json:"section_name"
}

for _, section := range sections {
   if value, err:=strconv.Atoi(string(section.ID)); err==nil {

   } else {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested your first variant. Why you set `float64` instead of `int`? In my example `1556895` is `int`, right?

Comment: The stdlib json unmarshaler unmarshals all numbers as float64. You can use a `json.Decoder` instead, call `decoder.UseNumber()`, and get json.Number values instead of float64.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?! How convert `int` to `json.RawMessage`? I need to set `int` value to `ID` field of the `Section` struct.

Comment: section.ID=json.RawMessage(json.Marshal(value)) works for all types of value.